# Autofac multitenancy not resolving type per tenant

Tags: autofac

I have an ASP.NET MVC/WebApi2 application where I use Autofac.Multitenant 3.1.1. I've setup a TenantIdentificationStrategy that identifies the tenant. I've also registered a type as InstancePerTenant. I have a tenant id for each customer and a special id for a background job where no context is present
The TenantIdentificationStrategy is invoked correctly and the id is found from the context, but the InstancePerTenant is only instatiated twice on boot: Once for the default lifetimescope (tenant is null) and once for the first tenant. If I log out and in with another tenant, the same type is reused and not a new one. I can see in the container, that a tenantlifetime scope is created per tenantid, but not 4 independent InstancePerTenant types. 
My tenant id code is:

```
    public class TenantIdentificationStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
    {
        public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenantId)
        {
            tenantId = null;
            try
            {
                var context = HttpContext.Current;
                if (context == null)
                {
                    tenantId = "jobservice";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (context.User?.Identity != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        var claims = context.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
                        tenantId = claims.FindAll(c => c.Type == "cID").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HttpException)
            {
                // Happens at app startup in IIS 7.0
            }
            return tenantId != null;
        }
    }
```

In Startup.cs - Configuration() I have (snippet):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
var container = builder.Build();
var tenantIdentifier = new TenantIdentificationStrategy();
mtContainer = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentifier, container);
```

And a registration module in a seperate assembly:

```
    public class RegistrationModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            ......
            builder.RegisterType<Office365ClientService>().As<IOffice365ClientService>().InstancePerDependency();
            builder.RegisterType<Office365Service>().As<IOffice365Service>().InstancePerDependency();
            builder.RegisterType<Office365ClientHttpProvider>().As<IHttpProvider>().InstancePerTenant();
            ......
        }
    }
```

The Office365ClientService has a dependency on IHttpProvider

Did I miss something?

Comment: You should provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - there's not enough info here to know whether or not you're missing anything. For example, we don't know what the app type is, how things are registered at app startup, etc.

Comment: Still not enough info, so I don't think I'll be able to come back and answer this. You don't show where you set the dependency resolver, you don't explain where things are being consumed - who uses the Office365 services and how often do those things get called? How does the background job interact with the web site and get started? What does a sample token look like for tenant ID? Have you set a breakpoint in the tenant ID strategy to see how often it's getting hit and when? What docs have you looked at to try to solve your own problem? Have you looked at the examples out there?

Comment: Since I won't be coming back, here's what I'll offer: [There is an MVC example with multitenant support](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/master/src/MultitenantExample.MvcApplication/Global.asax.cs). [The docs also have info on MVC integration.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html#asp-net-integration) I'd recommend setting a lot of breakpoints and trying to get something very simple working in your app before adding background jobs and extra stuff. Maybe a separate POC app? Sorry I can't be more help.